# "Steal" cores to other users: reduce user's processes priority

Tags: linux, process, multi-core

I'm working on a shared linux machine with multicores where I do have admin rights.
Is it possible to freeze all the processes of other users (or give them less priority to access to the CPUs) so that I can leverage all the machine computing power?

Comment: Doesn't sound like a nice thing to do....kinda destroys the word "shared"

Comment: Why so many downvotes? I see this as important system management option and of course server admin decides what user can do and how much they are allowed to consume resources. I can say that it is possible and you can give only specific cores to specific users/groups but i dont have time to dig it up just now (_hint: look for kernel modules for this_), however if I'll find some spare time I will add details here if still needed.

Comment: The title is unfortunate.

Comment: Thanks @SampoSarrala for understanding the importance of this question. To the others, I apologize for the unfortunate title (which I slightly changed).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's unclear what you mean by steal cores; however, if your process isn't very [nice](http://linux.about.com/library/cmd/blcmdl1_nice.htm), then the linux scheduler will give your application more computing time on the cores.  Do you really have a threaded / multiprocessing application that can leverage more than one core at once?

Syntax (as root):

```
nice -n -19 <cmd and args>
```

Another option is [`cpulimit`](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/cpu-usage-limiter-for-linux/).  This could be used per-process to slow something down.